# Attempting to check for whole numbers results in NaN

Tags: javascript

Let's say I cast my vote for 1, this if else statement will spit out "Invalid Response".
I'm really scratching my head over this one, as I'm sure you have guessed I am at the very beginning of my programming journey. Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working?

```js
answer = prompt
  (`What is your favourite programming language?\n0: JavaScript\n1: Python\n2: Rust\n3: C++\n(Write option number)`);
    if (answer >= 0 && answer <= 4 && answer == Math.floor(answer)) {
      this.answers[answer] += 1;
      console.log(poll.answers);
    } else {
      console.log(`Invalid Response`);      
    }
  },
```

Comment: `answer` is a string and not a number. Convert that to a number first before performing any numerical/mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Where is `this.answers` defined? Where is `this.answers[answer]` initialized?

Comment: Also, to check if a number is not a fraction, you can do -> `Number.isInteger(answer)`